# Android Activity tag android:name MD5 changed in Manifest file without changing any code

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created an android build in 10 March 2018(#1234) then created the same version build in 15 May 2018(#1245). In both the builds i there is an issue of changing the class name in android manifest file. I don't know what xamarin changed its build process so i am getting the different class name.

I am showing you the exact scenario:

In #1234 i am getting the string of activity with name like below

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="md5601603957bd95d32f86ccea34c18d6a7.SplashActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

In #1245 i am getting the string of activity with name like below

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="md5b3a0d56d6e26694c48a179fb000dfbaa.SplashActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

So the difference is in the android:name tag of activity. Why it is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original MD5-based package names used the assembly version as part of the generation process which caused issues when using wildcards in your assembly version description. We fixed this by no longer using the assembly version as part of the MD5 package name generation and this was introduced in 15.7 which explains the difference.

For more details regarding this change, please see the following open source commits:

https://github.com/xamarin/Java.Interop/commit/429dc2a68579c9a820f03a7f09f35da3db9cd54a

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/e5b1c92c192612d1a292a0ce35ea77a72f38eb48

To avoid issues around MD5 generation, you can read the following documentation on **Android Callable Wrapping Naming**:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java-integration/android_callable_wrappers/#Android_Callable_Wrapper_Naming

Answer (score 5):

The MD5 name of the Android Callable Wrapper is generated by using the MD5SUM of the full assembly qualified name and namespace name (since `Xamarin.Android` 5.1).

One of the huge variables in the use of the full assembly qualified name is if you are using `AssemblyVersion` that contain wildcards, the MD5SUM changes on every build. If you do not use version wildcards, but manually change the version, the full assembly qualified name is changed and thus the MD5SUM is changed.

You should ***never*** manually reference that **MD5-based string** in your code, you should use `Java.Lang.Class.FromType` to obtain the Java class name as a string:

```
Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SomeDotNetClassName)).Name
```

If you are "sharing" the Java class name outside of your app, you can bypass the MD5 auto-naming scheme and hard-code a Java class name using the `Name` parameter of the various Attribute classes:

```
[Activity(Name ="com.sushihangover.SatelliteLaunchWindows.MainList", Label = Consts.Label,  MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", RoundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_round_launcher", Theme = "@style/Theme.SushiHangover.Main")]
public class MainActivity : ReactiveAppCompatActivity<LaunchDatesRecyclerViewModel>
{
    ~~~
}
```

Comment: Hello, Actually we have release version v1.0, v1.1, v1.2, v1.3 the build is generated the same class name using md5sum but when we generate the build for v1.4 then it is changed. We didnt changed anything. So my question is as per you said it should changed every release(build) it was not in my case. But now it is changed in v1.4. how?

Comment: @DigvijayRajput Is that version you are quoting the Android APK version, or one of the assembly version in question? (two totally different things)

Comment: @sushil, These are released versions of apk. About Assembly versions we are using 3-4 pcl files for sharing the code every project having its own Assembly.info file. I have checked all files for every project they are having version 1.0.* or 1.0.0 (ex: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]). The Droid project having the unchanged assembly version (1.0.0). Is that assembly version you are talking?

Comment: @DigvijayRajput Yes

Comment: @SushilHangover So do you have any clue that why it is changed? or you may know that how we can encrypt from MD5SUM to the assembly qualified name? so that i would know that what is the change?

Comment: @DigvijayRajput MD5 hashes are theoretically impossible to reverse directly.... You can look at the source code and review the build task GenerateJavaStubs as the AWC mapping starts there and spawns off into build task  JavaCallableWrapperGenerator, etc... to see how the naming is done... So if you rebuild `v1.3` again (assuming you have source version control of some type) and not your latest v1.4 using the current Xamarin.Android that you have installed you get a different MD5?

Comment: @Sushil, If i rebuild the `v1.3` version again the strange thing happens now i get the new md5 class name which i am getting with `v1.4`. Is it possible as i have up to date Xamarin.Android so when i rebuild `v1.3` using that it gives me the different md5 name?